# php constants in a javascript file | Add PHP Inside JS

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, constants, advanced-custom-fields

I'm working on a Quiz project. It needs modification constants in javascript files.

```
 const questions=[
   {
    q:'where is the capital of India',
    options:['New Delhi','Kolkatta','Varanashi','Agra'],
    answer:1
   },
   {
    q:'Who is the Prime Minister of India',
    options:['Amit Shah','Narendra Modi','Rahul Gandhi','None of the above'],
    answer:2
   },
   {
    q:'where is the capital of India',
    options:['New Delhi','Kolkatta','Varanashi','Agra'],
    answer:1
   }
]
```

But we need to add PHP on constant.

Try this, but not working...

```
      const questions=[
  {
    q:'<?php echo the_field("q_1"); ?>',
    options:['(<?php echo the_field("option_1"); ?>)','(<?php echo the_field("option_2"); ?>)','(<?php echo the_field("option_3"); ?>)','(<?php echo the_field("option_4"); ?>)'],
    answer:'<?php echo the_field("answer_1"); ?>'
   },
   {
    q:'<?php echo the_field("q_2"); ?>',
    options:['<?php echo the_field("option_1_2"); ?>','<?php echo the_field("option_2_2"); ?>','<?php echo the_field("option_3_2"); ?>','<?php echo the_field("option_4_2"); ?>'],
    answer:'<?php echo the_field("answer_2"); ?>'
   },
   {
    q:'<?php echo the_field("q_3"); ?>',
    options:['<?php echo the_field("option_1_3"); ?>','<?php echo the_field("option_2_3"); ?>','<?php echo the_field("option_3_3"); ?>','<?php echo the_field("option_4_3"); ?>'],
    answer:'<?php echo the_field("answer_3"); ?>'
   }
]
```

[Here is the full code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hkGZcBaVo3wLFrv2vcVmHhByW2PAeUlG/view)

Comment: Can you print this 
let q1 = '<?php echo the_field("q_1"); ?>';
console.log(q1);
upper const variable

Comment: can I know from where 'the_field' variable come from ?

Comment: if you are trying to run php code in JavaScript file..it is not possible. PHP is a server side language..it needs preprocessing...but JavaScript executes in front end.

Comment: @DasunManathunga using WordPress plugin ACF. It is not a big complex code. just need to replace the text with php.

Comment: If it's a javascript file, then no, you cannot put a PHP variable in it, since the file will not go through the PHP processor. Best you can do is place it in a script section of the php file  so that the javascript can pick it up

Answer (score 0):

If you print your JavaScript using PHP you could achieve the same result using the following code:

```php
<?php

$questions = [
    [
        q => the_field("q_1"),
        options => [
            the_field("option_1"), 
            the_field("option_2"), 
            the_field("option_3"), 
            the_field("option_4")
        ],
        answer => the_field("answer_1")
    ],
    [
        q => the_field("q_2"),
        options => [
            the_field("option_1_2"), 
            the_field("option_2_2"), 
            the_field("option_3_2"), 
            the_field("option_4_2")
        ],
        answer => the_field("answer_2")
    ],
    [
        q => the_field("q_3"),
        options => [
            the_field("option_1_3"), 
            the_field("option_2_3"), 
            the_field("option_3_3"), 
            the_field("option_4_3")
        ],
        answer => the_field("answer_3")
    ],
    // ... more options here
];
$output = [];

foreach($questions as $question) {
    $q = new stdClass();
    $q->q = $question['q'];
    $q->options = $question['options'];
    $q->answer = $question['answer'];
    array_push($output, $q);
}
```

and then, later in your HTML do something like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    const $questions = <?php echo json_encode($output); ?>;

    console.log($questions);
</script>
```